# Set property value of QObject by index, not name

Tags: qt, qmetaobject

In my publisher-subscriber class the Qt components subscribe by their property names. The publisher maps the pairs `<QObject*,PropertyName (as QString)>` to the names of the publishable variables.

```
{ VarName -> [(QObject*, PropName)] }
```

On variable change, the list of subscribed QObjects are called using setProperty:

```
subscriber->setProperty( PropName.toAscii().constData(), NewValue );
```

I'd like to optimize the conversion from QString to char*. Also I assume, internally in setProperty the property setter function is found by going through the list of const* and string compare.

QMetaObject provides the method:

```
int QMetaObject::indexOfProperty(const char *name) const
```

which I could use during the subscription to get the index and later on the value change use only Index instead of the string-name.

But how can I invoke the property setter by the index? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I failed to find such an API that allows setting a property by its index.

Comment: @vahancho You get a `QMetaProperty` using the index and then interact with it, see reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `QMetaObject` you would get the [`QMetaProperty`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaproperty.html) using `QMetaObject::property(QMetaObject::indexOfProperty(qPrintable(propName)))` and then you can call `QMetaPropety::write(subscriber, value)` (or `writeOnGadget()`).  (Obviously you'd store the index instead of the name, that code is just for example.)

And/or for a slight efficiency gain you could use `QByteArray` to store the property names since that's one less conversion step to/from `char *`.